# Object tracking или Отслеживание объектов на изображениях

Tags: python, pytorch

Я использую модель faster rcnn для обнаружения объектов:

```
def create_model(num_classes):
    ''' Создание модели '''
    model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2(weights=None)

    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
    return model
```

Предположим, я обнаруживаю и подсчитываю бутылки с coca-cola, fanta & sprite на полках различных магазинов. **И проблема заключается в том, что иногда в модель подается несколько изображений одной и той же полки, получается, что модель детектит и подсчитывает одну и ту же полку несколько раз. Какой алгоритм можно использовать для обнаружения таких изображений? Получается что это не одно и то же изображение, а разные изображений одних и тех же объектов, которые могли быть сняты немного с разных ракурсов.**

Comment: Non Maxima Suppression (NMS)  напр.. http://aishelf.org/yolo-nms/

Comment: @nexoma А причем здесь NMS? NMS ведь подавляет ограничивающие рамки, наложенные друг на друга (на одном изображении)? и NMS уже встроен в Faster Rcnn, а мне требуется выявить похожие изображения.

Comment: видимо, не осознал вопрос.